# Azure AD OAuth2 redirects back to Microsoft login after entering credentials

Tags: php, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm using [oauth2-azure](https://github.com/TheNetworg/oauth2-azure).

After redirecting to the login page `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?state=zzz&scope=&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org&client_id=xxx` the following pattern loops:

1. Enter credentials and login
2. Page redirects to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf` (without any GET params)
3. Goto 1

The question is, why doesn't it redirect to `http://example.org`? Why does it keep redirecting to the login form? No errors are available on the page.

Code:

```
use TheNetworg\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Azure;

// ...

$clientId = "xxx";
$clientSecret = "yyy";
$redirectUri = "http://example.org";

$provider = new Azure(array
(
    "clientId"      => $clientId,
    "clientSecret"  => $clientSecret,
    "redirectUri"   => $redirectUri
));

if (!isset($_GET["code"]))
{
    $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();
    $_SESSION["oauth2state"] = $provider->getState();
    header("location: $authUrl");
    die();
}

// Validate state, get access token etc...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem by setting `common` and microsoft account login :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xxxxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A16468%2F&scope=openid
```

In azure ad 1.0 ,we could add microsoft account as external user in tenant , when we use microsoft account login with `common` in a multi-tenant environment , identity provider can't know which tenant you want that microsoft account to login . To fix that issue , you could use specific tenant :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xxxxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A16468%2F&scope=openid
```

Or use Azure AD V2.0 :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview

Comment: Replacing `common` with tenant id fixed the issue, thank you! Couldn't get Azure AD V2.0 to work though, it returned `https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=1033#error=unauthorized_client&error_description=The+client+does+not+exist...` url with every valid scope I tried.

Comment: app of azure ad v2.0 should registered in apps.dev.microsoft.com . read more about [what's different about the v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare) .

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that as well.